# Написать запрос , с условием , которое не позволит вставить дублирующее значение

Tags: sql, sql-server

У меня есть вот такая таблица Расписания:

```
CREATE TABLE [Расписание]
    (
     [День_недели] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
     [Номер_пары] Int NOT NULL,
     [Номер_группы] nvarchar (50)NOT NULL,
     [Номер_лабаратории] Int DEFAULT 50 NOT NULL,
     [Код_дисциплины] Int NOT NULL,
     [Код_преподаветеля] Int NOT NULL
    )
ALTER TABLE [Расписание]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Расписание] PRIMARY KEY ([День_недели],
[Номер_пары],[Номер_группы],[Код_дисциплины],[Код_преподаветеля])
```

Запрос должен осуществлять вставку записей , но при этом если у меня будет у одного препода 2 разные группы например на 4 паре , он не должен будет проинсертить.

Есть запрос который удалит:

```
DELETE T
FROM(
    SELECT *, Повтор_пар = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY Номер_лабаратории
        ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM Расписание
)
AS T
WHERE Повтор_пар > 1
```

Comment: то есть ты приводишь sql-запрос (точнее два запроса), и в самом вопросе у тебя вопрос по поводу sql, а в метках ты ставишь WPF? А в чем логика?

Comment: *если у меня будет у одного препода 2 разные группы например на 4 паре , он не должен будет проинсертить* Для этого следует создать уникальный индекс по соответствующему выражению. `([День_недели], [Номер_пары], [Код_преподаветеля])`.